# How to log data (separate levels) to a particular appenders in Log4Net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have 2 appenders that I have created and I would like to log all error messages to the ErrorAppender and all of the info messages to the InfoAppender.

However my InfoAppender is occasionally picking up an error message.

I am wondering if I need to use a filter instead of the threshold.

My appenders:

1. ErrorAppender has a threshold value of "ERROR"
2. InfoAppender has a threshold value of "INFO"

My config:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />  
</root>
```

In my code I am using ILOG.Error() or ILOG.Info() to log my messages.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I have the setting set as the linked article and still have the issue.

Comment: In order to get the desired results a filter range was needed to accomplish this.  The threshold setting did not accomplish this be itself.

Comment: I guess when they log it as duplicate (and it's not) then there is no reviving this question.